# ColorToDec function (clRed = $0000FF)?

Tags: delphi

How do you convert a TColor value to a decimal representation (clRed = $0000FF)?

Comment: That's a hexadecimal representation, not a decimal representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colour constants in Delphi (and the Windows API) are simply signed integers. They are normally represented in Hexadecimal format (with a leading $).

It is defined in Graphics.pas as  TColor = -$7FFFFFFF-1..$7FFFFFFF;

Positive values ($00000000 -> $00FFFFFF) are in BGR format: $00FF0000 = blue, $0000FF00 = green, $000000FF = red.

Negative values refer to user defineable system colours, like the colour for window text (clWindowText).

To convert a TColor to it's display value, use

```
IntToHex(Colour, 8);
```

or use

```
Format('%.8x', [Colour]);
```

In older versions of Delphi, IntToHex calls Format(), in later versions it is directly implemented and is much faster.

To convert to HTML #RRBBGG format, you need to reverse the red and green values in RRUZ answer:

```
function FromTColorDelphiToHTML(Color : TColor) : string;
begin
   Result :='#'+
     IntToHex(GetRValue(Color), 2) +
     IntToHex(GetGValue(Color), 2) +
     IntToHex(GetBValue(Color), 2) ;
end;
```

Comment: Why would you concatenate three strings instead of calling `Format()` once with the `'%.2x%.2x%.2x'` format string and the three channel values?

Comment: Would need to profile it to see which is faster. Format isn't very fast as it has to parse the input. IntToHex of later delphi versions calls the same routine as IntToStr.

Comment: Using Delphi 2009 the solution with three `IntToHex()` calls and string concatenation is about 25 % slower than the single `Format()` call. But for me it's not about performance: From the format string one can see at a glance what the end result will be.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
uses
   Graphics;

function ColorToHex(const color: TColor): string;
begin
   result := '$' + IntToHex(ColorToRGB(color), 6);
end;
```

Comment: I won't vote this down, but this won't work according to Bill Miller's  specification. His example showed (clRed = $0000FF), so I'm guessing he wants the TColor BGR format. ColorToHex(clRed) returns $FF0000.

Comment: Ah, leave it.. Bill Miller's own solution does it like you did it.. whatever guys. :)  +1 after all then

Comment: @Wouter: On **my** Delphi 4 this `ColorToHex(clRed)` above does return `$0000FF`, YMMV of course.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function FromTColorDelphiToHex(Color : TColor) : string;
begin
   Result :='$'+
     IntToHex(GetBValue(Color), 2) +
     IntToHex(GetGValue(Color), 2) +
     IntToHex(GetRValue(Color), 2) ;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always been a fan of "Format" for such uses:

```
function ColorToHex(color: TColor): String;
begin
   Result := Format('$%.6x', [integer(aColor)]);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

after several hours I came up with this.

```
function ColorToDecimal( Color: TColor ): string;
var
  AColor: integer;
  DecimalColor: integer;
begin
  DecimalColor := ColorToRGB( Color );
  FmtStr( Result, '%s%0.8x', [ HexDisplayPrefix, DecimalColor ] );
end;
```

I think it works but still testing...

Comment: Nosredna mentioned it already. This is not decimal, but hexadecimal. ColorToDecimal would be `IntToStr(clRed)`. Your function doesn't match your example by the way... ColorToDecimal(clRed) is going to return $00FF0000 and not $0000FF.

Comment: @Wouter: Same here, `ColorToDecimal(clRed)` is **not** going to return `$00FF0000` but `$000000FF`. It might be a good idea to try stuff next time before commenting.